# Maps java script API to Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a real estate web platform with Django and postgresql back-end. I have implemented maps API in my HTML template in order to show where the real estate is located. 
The code:

```
 <!--Map-->

      <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <style>
            #map{
              height:250px;
              width: 100%;
            }
          </style>
          <div id="map"></div>
          <script>
            function initMap(){
              var myLatLng = {lat:-33.90, lng:151.16};
              var options = {
                zoom:10,
                center:myLatLng
              };
              var map = new
              google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
            }
          </script>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Markers will be added in the next step because I have to figure out how I can retrieve my LAT and LNG values from the database and display them inside the script. Does anyone have the answer?

To explain that a bit further, I want to make something like

```
<script>
            function initMap(){
              var myLatLng = {lat:{{listing.geo_lat}}, {{listing.geo_lng}}};
              var options = {
                zoom:10,
                center:myLatLng
              };
```

But I have tried that and it seems that either google api cant read the proper format of my values or listing.geo_lat is not properly working inside the script.

Comment: 1) That's not creating a marker and 2) you are missing `lng:` in `{lat:{{listing.geo_lat}}, {{listing.geo_lng}}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont really know if it's an optimised solution but that works.

```
      <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <style>
            #map{
              height:250px;
              width: 100%;
              max-width: none;
            }
          </style>
          <div id="map"></div>
          <script>

            let lat = "{{listing.lat}}";
            let lng = "{{listing.lng}}";
            let geo_lat = parseFloat(lat);
            let geo_lng = parseFloat(lng);

            function initMap(){
              var myLatLng = {lat:geo_lat, lng:geo_lng};
              var options = {
                zoom:11,
                center:myLatLng
              };
              var map = new
              google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),options);
            }
          </script>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That's still not creating a marker + this is the most basic implementation of a map with what seems to be dynamic coords for its center. What is this supposed to answer? What help would it provide to anyone else?